# SQL Error (1005): Can't create table (errno: -1)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

When I execute the table create I get the error: SQL Error (1005): Can't create table (errno: -1)

```
CREATE TABLE `employee_audit` (
      `employee_audit_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `employee_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `employeeNumber` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `firstName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`employee_audit_id`)
    )
```

Comment: runs ok, did you restart the service to see if everything is ok

Comment: @nbk : I think it got messed up when we first run the create table and now it does not allow us to create one. Haven't tried to restart as its a production server.

Comment: Check the error logs. the query is ok How do you execute your query command workbench?

Comment: @nbk : The query log does not show any errors for this particular table